# Need help with proving the recursion

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, recursion

Let $p_{k}(n)$ indicate the number of partitions of n into k parts. Prove:
$$p_{k}(n) = p_{k-1}(n-1) + p_{k}(n-k)$$

Example: There are two partitions of $5$ into three parts.

$5 = 3+1+1$

$5 = 2+2+1$

My approach was going to start out by proving by induction. But quickly, I don't even seem to understand what this recursion is talking about. Is it possible to even do it by induction? Any help would be great. I've proved a couple of recursion problems by induction like the Fibonacci ones but I can't wrap my head around this one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need induction.

Let $A_k(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts where (at least) one of the parts is $1$, and let $B_k(n)$ be the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts all of which are greater than $1$.

Then it is clear that $p_k(n) = A_k(n) + B_k(n)$, and it is also easy to see that $A_k(n) = p_{k-1}(n-1)$ and $B_k(n) = p_k(n-k)$.

Comment: What made you decide to choose one of the parts being 1? Is there a rule for partitions? This is my first time dealing with a problem with partitions so I am just confused about it.

Comment: That's what the first term in the recursion says, the number of partitions of $n-1$ into $k-1$ parts. That means we get that term from taking these partitions and adding a $1$ part to each to obtain a partition of $n$ into $k$ parts. For the other term, in case you haven't figured it out, you take the partitions of $n-k$ into $k$ parts, and increment every part by $1$.

Comment: Ahh, I get it now. Thank you!